# Subplot with multiple subplots

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am drawing 4 sets of 12 plots (i.e. 48 plots in total). I want to combine the 12 plots within each of the 4 sets into one figure. However, I do not know how to combine the plots. At the moment, I am only drawing the 48 plots.

The dictionary I am referring to in the following contains 4 dictionaries, in turn containing 12 datasets each:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

for j in dic:
    for i in dic[j]:
        df = pd.concat(dic[j][i].values(), ignore_index=True)
        var = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=10000)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.histplot(df['Z'], stat='density', ax=ax)
        sns.kdeplot(var, color='r', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Move the creation of the figure into the first loop, rather than the inner loop, to create 4 figures each containing the 12 datasets

Comment: @DavidG I want to get 4 figures, each containing 12 figures for each respective dataset. As far as I understand, what you suggest results in 4 single figures.

Comment: Oh I see. You will still have to move the figure creation to the first loop, but instead create 12 subplots inside that figure. Then loop through the axes at the same time as you are looping through the data

Comment: @DavidG Alright - thanks. I tried to figure out how to actually implement this. But thus far, I have failed. If you could provide a quick answer I would thankfully accept it.

Comment: Actually, I found a solution thanks to your advice, which I will post as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GenG, I found the solution:

```
temp_1 = [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
temp_2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]

for j in dic:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,4)
    for i, t, k in zip(dic[j], temp_1, temp_2):
        df = pd.concat(dic[j][i].values(), ignore_index=True)
        var = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=10000)
        sns.histplot(df['Z'], stat='density', ax=ax[t][k])
        sns.kdeplot(var, color='r', ax=ax[t][k])
```